# Jupyter Notebook specify path to directory for concatenation of multiple .csv files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

The following code works great for concatenating multiple .csv files into one. All of these .csv files reside in the same directory. The problem is that it only works if my current file is in the same directory as those multiple .csv files. I have tried different syntaxes to specify the path to the directory where those mutliple .csv files reside, but no success. I wondered where I should specify the path to the .csv files directory in the below code. Btw, I am working in Jupyter Notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

filepaths = [f for f in os.listdir(".") if f.endswith('.csv')]
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, filepaths)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.listdit(dir)` lists the files in the path `dir`. In your example, you have `dir='.'`, which corresponds to the current working directory (the directory from where you run your script). You can change this variable to the directory where your `.csv` files reside.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

base_dir = os.path.join('path', 'to', 'files')
filepaths = [f for f in os.listdir(base_dir) if f.endswith('.csv')]
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, filepaths)
```

### Slower version with globbing

You can avoid using `endswith()` by globbing,

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob

base_dir = os.path.join('path', 'to', 'files')
filepaths = [f for f in glob.glob(f'{base_dir}*.csv')]
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, filepaths))
```

This expands the wildcard `*` to find all files that ends with `.csv` in `base_dir`.

Answer (score 1):

In `os.listdir`, `"."` represents current directory.

You can specify instead `os.path.join('.', 'subdir', 'subsubdir')` to list files in `subdir/subsubdir/`.

Complete code.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

filepaths = [f for f in os.listdir(os.path.join('.', 'subdir', 'subsubdir')) if f.endswith('.csv')]
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, filepaths)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just replace `os.listdir(".")` with `os.listdir("csvFilesPath")` as indicated in the previous answer it works. I tried it